# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error en el android manifest?

Tags: android, android-studio

Como puedo solucionar este problema en el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, al definir `Activities`  creo que siempre me sale un error y no se como solucionarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es mejor que incluyas el código en tu pregunta y no solo la imagen. Mira estas guías: _[ask]_ y _[mcve]_.

Comment: Es más útil poner el texto del código que una imagen y también el mensaje de error que muestra cuando colocas el puntero sobre la parte del error, ya que siempre te da información importante del mismo. Todo parece indicar que tu `MainActivity` no está extendiendo de  `AppCompatActivity` es decir, tu clase debe empezar así: `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity ... `

Comment: Gracias @Davlio , es duplicado sin duda, solo que no se puede marcar hasta que exista una respuesta correcta, seguramente procederá la eliminación ya que el OP no da retroalimentación sobre lo que pregunta... esperemos un poco.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero actualices a la versión de android studio 2.3.3, puede ser algún error en conflicto con SDK's o algo así, trata de trabajar siempre con las ultimas versiones he solucionado algunos inconvenientes que tenia simplemente actualizando los sdk y android studio.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso puedes posicionar el puntero del mouse en el texto que indica un problema y te arrojará más detalles sobre este, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En este caso el problema es que la `Activity` que estas definiendo en realidad no es una `Activity`!**.

Asegura que la clase que indicas, en verdad extienda de `Activity` o `AppCompatActivity`, por ejemplo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
 ...
 ...
```

de esta forma podrás declararla sin problema dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
```