# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error en el android manifest <activity>?

Tags: android

Cómo puedo solucionar este problema en el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, al definir *Activities* siempre me sale error y no se como solucionarlo  .
Tengo *android studio 2.3.3*:

En la parte del  **activity** android: `name=".MainActivity"`, ME SALE: `ERROR (TOP LEVEL ELEMENT IS NOT COMPLETED)`, y me dice que tengo en el *manifest* 2 errores. 2 anvertencias y 2 errores tipograficos.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.samsung.frasesinfinitas"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[image: AndroidManifest][image: Archivo.java]

Comment: No es necesario agregar una nueva respuesta, agrega detalles adicionales para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pregunta relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92761/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-solucionar-este-error-en-el-android-manifest

Comment: puedes adjuntar el error?

Answer (score 1):

Has probado colocando el nombre del package completo.

```
<activity 
    name="com.example.samsung.frasesinfinitas.MainActivity"
    ...>
<activity/>
```

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error indica el problema:

> ERROR (TOP LEVEL ELEMENT IS NOT COMPLETED)

en español:

> ERROR (EL ELEMENTO DE NIVEL SUPERIOR NO ESTÁ COMPLETADO)

Indica que debes cerrar todos los tags, en este caso agrega al final  `</manifest>` para cerrar todo el bloque:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.samsung.frasesinfinitas"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

  </manifest>
```

**En este caso revisando tu AndroidManifest.xml ya tiene el último tag, por lo tanto limpia y genera nuevamente tu  proyect**o:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para quien aun tenga este problema intente revisar que su versión target sea igual en `defaultConfig` del archivo `build.grandle(;app)`

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.

Comment: Por favor, agrega más detalles para ampliar tu respuesta, como código que funcione o citas de documentación.